# I can't use float + h3 too wide

Tags: html, css

[Link to site](http://projekcior.com/Plugins/FAQs%20plugin/index.html)

```
/*Align width 1170px*/
.align-1170{
    height: 100%;
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/*Align vertically*/
.align-vertically{
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}



/*Header*/

header{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1ccb56;

}

.logo{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.author{
    float: right;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

1. Why Can't I use float:right; to move "Author: projekcior.com" to right side 
   (with vertically alignment)?
2. Why my h3 tag is so wide? (650px)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An element that is **floated** is **automatically**

```
display: block;
```

use

```
h3 { display:inline-block; }
```

to manage your h3 width.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer your question in steps.

> Why Can't I use float:right; to move "Author: projekcior.com" to right side (with vertically alignment)?

Maybe because, you're not setting the margins to it. It actually is to the right side of the web page. I just tried to use margin for it.

```
p.white {
   margin: 20px;
}
```

Using this, it came down a bit from the top corner.

> Why my h3 tag is so wide? (650px)

Because you've not set any of the `width: value` to the element, so browser would automatically set the width. I used width property to minimize the size.

```
h3 {
   width: 200px;
}
```

Here is the screen shot for your page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hey Komon i guess you didn't write a proper css for your webpage so i tried to correct your page see the mentioned below **CSS** :-

**CSS**

```
.align-vertically {
    border: 1px solid;
}
.align-1170 {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1170px;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
}
h3 {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.author {
    float: right;
}
```

see the css and try to understand where u made mistake actually your parent div were not floated that's why your child div are not in control....

apply this css i guess through this you will achieve your desired results...

[image]